# ItextSharp crear pdf

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, itextsharp

Trabajo con Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2015

Estoy creando una estructura en un pdf para poner datos de un xml(factura electrónica).

Lo que necesito resolver es hacer la estructura donde voy a poner los datos, muestro una imagen de que es lo que necesito.
[image: estructura]

Donde dice logo necesito que este sin borde ahí voy a poner el logo de la empresa, donde dice datos de factura necesito unirlos para que se vea uno solo.

Pero entre las dos columnas necesito que haya un espacio.

El código que ocupo es el siguiente:

```
var path = @"D:\CrearPdfs";
        var doc = new Document();
        var table = new PdfPTable(2);

        table.AddCell("Logo sin bordes");
        table.AddCell("Datos de factura");
        table.AddCell("Datos de empresa");
        table.AddCell("Datos de factura");

     //   var datoFactura = new PdfPCell(table);
     //   datoFactura.Padding = 0f;
     //   table.AddCell(datoFactura);
     //   var datoF = new PdfPCell();
        //datoF.Colspan = 2;
     //   table.AddCell(datoF);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/Factura.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
```

Investigando he podido avanzar algo ya puedo tener la estructura que deseo solo necesito que ambas columnas estén divididas por un espacio ambas manteniendo su borde.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"D:\CrearPdfs";
        var doc = new Document();
        var table = new PdfPTable(2);

        var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Logo"));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Información de la Factura"));
        cell.Rowspan = 2;
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Información de la empresa"));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/Factura.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Imagen
[image: estructura 2]

Saludos!